# Why does CodeContracts warn me that "requires unproven: index < @this.Count" even though I have already checked the count?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have code that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private T bar;

    public Foo(IEnumerable<T> items)
        : base(items.ToList())
    {
        Contract.Requires(items != null);

        if (this.Any())
            this.bar = this[0]; // gives 'requires unproven: index < @this.Count'
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the `Any` check account for index 0? Am I doing something wrong, or does CodeContracts just not recognize this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ's `.Any` and the item accessor `[0]` are unrelated enough that Code Contracts hasn't been made to consider them to be the same thing. Since `this.bar` would be initialized using a default value anyway, it's probably best to just do this:

```
Contract.Requires(items != null);
this.bar = items.FirstOrDefault();
```

This would not only resolve the possibility of thread-safety which AakashM points out, but it is also slightly more performant. Since you know `this` is a collection (and therefore has a `.Count`), another option would be:

```
if(this.Count > 0)
    this.bar = this[0];
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I guess I could even skip the null-check if I'm using `FirstOrDefault`, since `bar` will initially have its default value anyway.

Comment: @Matthew: Yup, which makes for clearer, more concise code anyway!

Comment: The first code snippet is incorrect whenever T is a value type

Comment: @StriplingWarrior the updated code is still incorrect.  Consider the case where T is `int` and the first value is 0.  It will consider the collection empty.  Additionally I'm fairly certain that won't compile because you can't do equality comparisons on generic values

Comment: @StiplingWarrior, i verified the first sample no longer compiles

Comment: @Matthew: a key difference is that `.First()` will throw if the collection is empty, whereas `.FirstOrDefault()` won't. Which behaviour you need depends on your situation.

Comment: @Porges: Right, originally I was avoiding that issue by ensuring that the collection wasn't empty. But since I want the default when the collection is empty, I think `FirstOrDefault` is a much better way of solving the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

None of the LINQ methods are annotated with the `Contracts` API.  Hence when the verifier runs on this method it acquires no new data about the value of `Count`.  This is why you see the warning.

One way to work around this is to use `Assume` to tell the verifier the count is valid at this point.

```
if (this.Any()) {
  Contract.Assume(this.Count > 0);
  this.bar = this[0];
}
```